# What is the best way to organize daily user data in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am setting up a database using MySQL with the goal of storing data for a potentially large number of unique users. Each user will have some basic data associated with them - a unique username, when they joined the service, how many times they have used the service, in addition to a set of their personal preferences. I am planning on keeping one table called 'Users' dedicated to these fields.

However, there is a bunch of data with a specific schema that will be collected about that user during each session that they use the service. This data includes which user performed this session, the date of the session, what the user did, etc.

My thought process is the following: if I use a single table for users that includes data on each of their sessions, this seems inefficient because there would have to be either a column for each unique session, or a column containing more or less an array or list of sessions. If I wanted to keep this data for an indeterminate number of sessions, then the one-per-column idea would break down, because I believe there is a column limit. Updating an array within a single column also seems to be frowned upon, I think for reasons having to do with preserving the integrity of the data and maintaining the best possible organization.

So it seems like I want two tables, one for users, and another for sessions. Every time anybody completes a session, data about that session will be created as a new row in the 'Sessions' table, and each row would also have a foreign key linking that session to the particular user who completed it.

Is this a correct line of thought? If not, how should I think about this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes 2 tables: `tbl_users` and `tbl_sessions`, 1 to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you're pretty close. You should separate users and sessions, and you're looking at modeling a relationship. Each session only has one user, so it's a one-to-many relationship.

1 User (1 Row in the "Users" table) can have many Sessions (1 Row in the "Sessions" table)

The Foreign Key is the User ID in the Sessions table. This links each unique session (Which will have it's own Session ID I'm assuming) back to a unique User in the Users table.

If you're looking at a massive volume of users, which means a ton of sessions, you may want to consider options on how to help the sessions table not grow to be extremely huge and slow to query. If you're collecting this data on a daily basis, consider that you could "Partition" the table on dates:

[Partitioning on DateTime in MySQL](http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/partitioning-by-dates-the)

edit: typos